Approach to feature engineer mean columns to avoid data leakage?
I understand the intuition behind data leakage, but am not sure of a correct process to avoid it.  Suppose there were calculated columns for averages of particular groups, calculated and created within the full dataset.  In order to avoid leakage during testing and training, what is the correct approach?
Opt 1:

Drop mean columns in full set (set aside)
Create train/test split sets
Recalculate and recreate mean columns in the training set (mean is specific to the training data), then scale (fit and transform)
Recalculate and recreate mean columns in the test set (mean is specific to the test data) then scale (transform only)
Later use model to predict with original full dataset, using means calculated from full dataset

Or Opt 2:

Drop mean columns in full set (set aside)
Create train/test split sets
Recalculate and recreate mean columns in the training set (mean is specific to the training data), then scale (fit and transform)
Map the mean values calculated in train to the test set for those groups (mean is specific to the training data, now in the test data) then scale (transform only)
Later use model to predict with original full dataset, using means calculated from full dataset

What is considered the correct approach?
